# Stata - panel data from column data

Tags: panel, stata, reshape

Panel data newbie here! I have data in Stata in the following format:

```
Name    Company1    Company2    Company3    Company4    Company5    Company6
1985    6.0781      2.4766  1.4258  2.6508  13.2083
1986    6.4844      3.0938  2.1953  3.1351  15.7917
1987    10.1563 .2769   5.7109  3.6406  4.4058  15.5833
1988    10.4688 .4219   5.125   3.75    3.6767  8.1667
1989    11.0625 .4289   5.4453  3.9844  3.7288  10.25
1990    11.6875 .7206   6.875   5.6406  5.1974  8.6667
1991    13.6563 1.4863  10.1406 8.9687  5.6869  5.7083
1992    13.75   2.5522  12.2187 13  6.4681  10.875
1993    16.0938 2.6172  10.3437 16.4375 7.0826  13.6667
1994    16.3125 2.5313  9.9375  14  8.7387  12.125
1995    15.8125 3.9766  14.4375 12.5    8.8324  13.2083
```

I know I normally have to use the `reshape` command somehow, but I am not sure how. I try

```
reshape wide Name, i(Name) j(Name)
```

which obviously fails

```
(note: j = 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2
> 007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015)
no variables defined
r(111);
```

CompanyNumber (Number1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) will be the ID to be used in the panel data, and the year will be the time for each company respectively.

Any ideas how to `reshape` or w/e this data to be in proper panel data format?

How my data actually look like in Stata
[image: how my data really look in stata]

The error I get when I try to run nick cox code:
[image: what i get when i execute nick cox code]

Comment: You need to `reshape long`, not `wide`. Read carefully `help reshape`.

Comment: ok I will try this and come back to update with whether i solved it. thanks for the hint

Comment: In short, my code no longer works because you changed the variable names to which it applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sandbox data has implicit missing values, so the first two lines get omitted the way I read this in. I take that as being incidental. As @Roberto Ferrer clearly explained, this is an (utterly standard) `reshape long`.

```
clear 
input Name    Company1    Company2    Company3    Company4    Company5    Company6
1985    6.0781      2.4766  1.4258  2.6508  13.2083
1986    6.4844      3.0938  2.1953  3.1351  15.7917
1987    10.1563 .2769   5.7109  3.6406  4.4058  15.5833
1988    10.4688 .4219   5.125   3.75    3.6767  8.1667
1989    11.0625 .4289   5.4453  3.9844  3.7288  10.25
1990    11.6875 .7206   6.875   5.6406  5.1974  8.6667
1991    13.6563 1.4863  10.1406 8.9687  5.6869  5.7083
1992    13.75   2.5522  12.2187 13  6.4681  10.875
1993    16.0938 2.6172  10.3437 16.4375 7.0826  13.6667
1994    16.3125 2.5313  9.9375  14  8.7387  12.125
1995    15.8125 3.9766  14.4375 12.5    8.8324  13.2083
end 
reshape long Company, i(Name) 
rename (Company Name _j) (whatever year company) 
sort company year
list , sepby(company)


     +---------------------------+
     | year   company   whatever |
     |---------------------------|
  1. | 1987         1    10.1563 |
  2. | 1988         1    10.4688 |
  3. | 1989         1    11.0625 |
  4. | 1990         1    11.6875 |
  5. | 1991         1    13.6563 |
  6. | 1992         1      13.75 |
  7. | 1993         1    16.0938 |
  8. | 1994         1    16.3125 |
  9. | 1995         1    15.8125 |
     |---------------------------|
 10. | 1987         2      .2769 |
 11. | 1988         2      .4219 |
 12. | 1989         2      .4289 |
 13. | 1990         2      .7206 |
 14. | 1991         2     1.4863 |
 15. | 1992         2     2.5522 |
 16. | 1993         2     2.6172 |
 17. | 1994         2     2.5313 |
 18. | 1995         2     3.9766 |
     |---------------------------|
 19. | 1987         3     5.7109 |
 20. | 1988         3      5.125 |
 21. | 1989         3     5.4453 |
 22. | 1990         3      6.875 |
 23. | 1991         3    10.1406 |
 24. | 1992         3    12.2187 |
 25. | 1993         3    10.3437 |
 26. | 1994         3     9.9375 |
 27. | 1995         3    14.4375 |
     |---------------------------|
 28. | 1987         4     3.6406 |
 29. | 1988         4       3.75 |
 30. | 1989         4     3.9844 |
 31. | 1990         4     5.6406 |
 32. | 1991         4     8.9687 |
 33. | 1992         4         13 |
 34. | 1993         4    16.4375 |
 35. | 1994         4         14 |
 36. | 1995         4       12.5 |
     |---------------------------|
 37. | 1987         5     4.4058 |
 38. | 1988         5     3.6767 |
 39. | 1989         5     3.7288 |
 40. | 1990         5     5.1974 |
 41. | 1991         5     5.6869 |
 42. | 1992         5     6.4681 |
 43. | 1993         5     7.0826 |
 44. | 1994         5     8.7387 |
 45. | 1995         5     8.8324 |
     |---------------------------|
 46. | 1987         6    15.5833 |
 47. | 1988         6     8.1667 |
 48. | 1989         6      10.25 |
 49. | 1990         6     8.6667 |
 50. | 1991         6     5.7083 |
 51. | 1992         6     10.875 |
 52. | 1993         6    13.6667 |
 53. | 1994         6     12.125 |
 54. | 1995         6    13.2083 |
     +---------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks for your answer. Probably I was not clear enough. The company names are company1, company2 etc.. how can i use these for my panel data? I dont have any other columns at the moment

Comment: In turn I don't know quite what you are still asking. You now have panel data in the structure Stata prefers. If you wish you can `tsset company year` or `xtset company year`. Then everything depends on what analysis you want to do.

Comment: reshape long Company, i(Name)  What i mean is that there is no such thing as "Company" in my data.. Can you tell me sth that works with the way my data are structured?

Comment: The variable `company` is a numeric identifier for panels, absent a name as you explain. Stata doesn't care; in fact it requires a numeric identifier and extra text anywhere is optional. Start with `help xt`. `xtsum` will work.

Comment: maybe it's important to know that company1 company2 etc are the names of the columns and that in reality they are not named company1 company2 but exxon microsoft walmart etc so this "pattern matching" would not work. Is there some way to capture the actual column names instead ? "Name" is actually the name of the 1st column which hold the years (it is a bad name for a years column, i have to change that btw). And to answer another point you raised, some companies may not have data for some years. is there a way to deal with that ? (probably unbalanced panel?)

Comment: Unbalanced panels are allowed. But they aren't unbalanced because values are missing. They are unbalanced only if there are gaps.

Comment: i edited my initial post and i posted a screenshot of how my data actually look in stata, because i get an error when i try to execute your code. and then i post a picture of what i get when i try to run your code. thanks again

Comment: I gave a reproducible example. You have changed yours to an  example that we cannot reproduce exactly (screenshot is incomplete, can't be copied easily, etc.). But the code doesn't work any more because you applied it to a modified dataset. Your names are no longer `Company1` etc., so the code will not work and Stata is telling you that it knows nothing about what you refer to. `Company` must be a stub (prefix) for variable names. Change your variable names and you must change the syntax. In fact, the variable names now need editing before you can apply `reshape` at all.

Comment: Ok Nick I will accept your answer then although it doesn't work on my data. I will try to change the column names etc.

Comment: I am sure it is documented but I asked a question stating I am new to panel data on Stata and don't know every aspect of the documentation. I accept your answer, nevertheless if you can add something more to help me it would be very nice. Your answer is already very helpful though and helped me to get a little bit better in panel data. No reason for you to downvote by the way, not very polite.

Comment: I'd advise asking specific new questions as and when they occur with reproducible datasets and code.

Comment: Ok sorry my bad then. I assumed it was you because you are a little bit aggressive (dunno why). You can always upvote tho :D

Comment: Glad you found something in value in the exchange.